# d3js - Nodes don't get removed after transition on exit()

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a chart where I create nodes dynamically as time goes by.
After a certain time, I fade out the nodes and remove them.

I have the 2 variables:

- **data_nodes** which contains the data i'm binding the nodes to
- **node** which is the result of the d3.selectAll

I've tried the following

```
node = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(data_nodes, function(d){return d.id;});

node.exit.remove();
```

This works fine. When I inspect the SVG the nodes are removed properly

But when I do

```
node = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(data_nodes, function(d){return d.id;});

node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration+100)
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .remove();
```

The nodes fade out as expected but they don't get removed from the SVG element. The number of circles element in the DOM keeps on increasing.

When I check the size of **data_nodes** and **node** in the console, they're what I expect them to be but if I do a

d3.selectAll(".nodes") in the console I can see the number is wrong.

Thanks for the help.

**SOLUTION**:

It appears that my transition on exit() was too long and some of the nodes were coming back in, hence getting a transition assigned on enter().

Comment: Are you scheduling another transition during the transition? From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#remove): If a newer transition is scheduled on any of the selected elements, these elements will not be removed; however, the "end" event will still be dispatched.

Comment: I have transitions on:

* node after the selectAll i.e. for the nodes that are not new or removed

* node.enter()

Comment: Actually, very good point. I've realized that my transition on remove was taking long hence,some of the nodes would come back and have a .transition assign on .enter().

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could! I've turned the comment into an answer, since it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning the comments into an answer, since it was the issue:

You're scheduling another transition during your first transition, which cancels the `remove`.

From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#remove):

> If a newer transition is scheduled on any of the selected elements,
>   these elements will not be removed; however, the "end" event will
>   still be dispatched.